# MYSQL Unselect row when having same of first character

Tags: mysql, select

i have a table like this

```
| symbol  | value |
-------------------
| test    | 12    |
| yes     | 8     |
| test.m  | 13    |
| no      | 10    |
| nah.m   | 20    |
| nah     | 17    |
```

i want the result like this

```
| symbol  | value |
-------------------
| test    | 13    |
| yes     | 8     |
| no      | 10    |
| nah     | 20    |
```

if you see the table, i want to select record that have ".m" in the last characters when the record have a duplicate that don't have ".m" in the last characters and remove ".m".

anyone can help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: and for the test with value 12  ..?

Comment: @scaisEdge no, for the test with value of "test.m"

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.symbol, coalesce(t2.value, t1.value)
from t t1
left join t t2 on t1.symbol = concat(t2.symbol, '.m')
where t1.symbol not like '%.m'
```

Comment: Good answer. It should always be `t1.symbol` though. And the case expressions can be written simpler with `coalesce`. Hence: `select t1.symbol, coalesce(t2.value, t1.value) from ...`.

Comment: sorry mate, it still show the first one, not the ".m" value

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE and group by

```
 select 
   case when locate('.', symbol )> 0 
                then sustr(symbol, 1, locate('.', symbol ) -1) 
                else symbol 
        end as my_symbol,
  max(value)
 from my_table
 group by my_symbol
```

Comment: Is `value` for `.m` must be always greater than value without `.m`?

Comment: I have used max for select the greatest  .. like in your sample  .. you can use the aggregation function you prefer ..

Comment: I say about case when we have two records: test:12 and test.m:11. In your case will be 11 instead of 12.

Comment: You want the value related to test.m ?

Comment: It says @Zaid Yasyaf in his comment above

Comment: @mnv no mate, random value is given